# How do I disable the 'EnableLinkRedirect' property in order to fetch data from the event hub without port 104XX?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I'm using a Connection string to connect with the Azure Event Hub.

In order to avoid the usage of TCP ports 104XX Microsoft has [documented](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide.md) to turn the **[EnableAmqpLinkRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.amqp.amqptransportsettings.enablelinkredirect?view=azure-dotnet)** property to **false**. The **default** is **True**

The **EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder** does not have this property at all. And the **ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder** creates a connection string that the EventHubClient does not accept.

So... how do I then disable this flag in order to avoid the usage of port 104xx ?

```cs
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Illegal connection string parameter name 'EnableAmqpLinkRedirect'
Parameter name: connectionString
  Source=Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder.ParseConnectionString(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(String connectionString)
   at Nodinite.LogAgent.PickupService.Helpers.AzureEventHubHelper.GetEventHubClient() in C:\Projects\Nodinite\LogAgent.PickupService\Nodinite.LogAgent.PickupService\Helpers\EventHubHelper.cs:line 59
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `EnableLinkRedirect` feature was implemented by the `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging` library and enabled by default.  The implementation was not brought forward into the `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` library, which is why you're unable to find a means to disable it.

That feature works by establishing a connection to the Event Hubs gateway using the standard AMQP ports (5671, 5672) and requesting that the service provide discovery for partition nodes to directly connect, which is where the 104xx port range would be used.

By default, the service does not attempt to redirect and the `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` library does not opt-in to that feature when connecting.  As a result, you should only be seeing Event Hubs traffic over the standard AMQP ports.